# 'module' object has no attribute 'date_range' in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning pandas in Python.Below is my code in Terimal:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
```

Then I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'date_range'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What does `print(pd.__file__)` show?  Maybe you're shadowing the pandas module with one of your own.

Comment: @DSM It shows "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.pyc
"

Comment: What about `print(pd.version.version)`?

Comment: @DSM It shows "0.7.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find `date_range` because you're using pandas version 0.7.0, which is very old (~9 Feb 2012) in pandas time-- the current stable version (29 Jan 2015) is 0.15.2.

You're going to want to upgrade, not only because of bug fixes and new features, but because many of the examples you're going to find on the web won't work for you otherwise.

Comment: You know, the pandas docs aren't very helpful, no "Introduced in 0.x" anywhere.

Comment: @epx, so did you succeed? What was the command you use to perform the upgrade?